# How to fire .NET code in my ArcGIS application from javascript?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, javascript, .net, vb.net

So I'm developing a .NET desktop application for ArcGIS in VB. As a new part of the application I have developed an SVG / Javascript map as a 'loading screen' where you select your dataset to load into ArcMap. This map is currently held in a html doc and displayed in an html viewer in a windows form. My question is this:

Is it possible for javascript events/functions in my web map to fire .NET code in my application? Can I pass variables from javascript to .NET? Etc...

I imagine this will be quite tricky if possible, as you won't want any old javascript on a website to start messing with your running .NET applications. I'm willing to hack this all together if there's a way.

Thanks.

EDIT: To be clear, this is **not** an ASP.NET (server side) web application, this is a purely vb.net desktop application. So I think AJAX / Postback solutions won't work in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're putting a WebBrowser control in a Winforms application? I believe what you want to do can be used with [the `WebBrowser.ObjectForCallback` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.objectforscripting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (useful examples are on that page) and a set of callbacks for your implementation.

Comment: Hi Jason. Yes I'm using the webbrowser control. That looks perfect, I should be able to do exactly what I need to do using that property. Many thanks.  +1